# Can I Access/Edit Files in a Pre-Made Image Library Server in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtualbox

I downloaded a library server image then imported it in Virtual Box.

I started the Virtual Machine and run the system installed through my browser. As a newbie, I am wondering if I could see the real files in my server and edit it for my own use. I wanted to see the location of my server files and manipulate it. How will I do that, when all I see is entirely a black screen just like the image below?

[image: My Virtual Box]

I can access the files through web browser,just like the image below.

[image: Accessing the server through the Web Browser]

I need to modify/add some files in the server for its customization. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy direct access to the files inside a VirtualBox image.

The easy way might be this: If those who released it allow making modifications to the server, then they might have written how to do it (maybe by providing a web interface to change what you need).

If it's not available, there's still a way to do it (requires knowledge in Linux): download a Linux live CD, add this image as a second drive, boot the live CD and mount the partition in which you want to change the files.

Comment: I can access the files through web browser. But I need to modify/add some files in the server for its customization.

Comment: If you have some knowledge in Linux, try using 'ssh' (PuTTY on Windows) to the server address (it may require username/password which you need to get). If you don't have username/password then the other option I mentioned would give you full access to the filesystem.